# Why is my discussion downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, discussions-space

I have a discussion https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77980534/recommendation-on-hosting-needed with even some replies. It seems not to violate any rules. Recently it has been downvoted.

What is bad with my discussion or what rule does it violate?

Comment: Seems to break the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines) *"Such posts should aim to start a discussion about the software or tool; they should not consist solely of a review/opinion."* to me. It looks like it's only looking for opinions, not a discussion.

Comment: Someone found the discussion not useful or unclear.

Comment: Why would it need to violate any rules to be found not useful, or uninteresting?

Comment: Suggesting to create a new AWS account when your free trial runs out (which is probably against the ToS) is probably also not going to net you upvotes from AWS employees. But leaving that aside, your post gives (imho) too little information about your application. Which language, frameworks, databases, ... do you require?

Comment: I downvoted it because asking for something that is perpetually free seems weird to me. Yea, it'd be awesome if all things in life could be free perpetually. but.. at a certain point the thing should provide a value worth spending a few bucks a year on, no? If not why should it exist? The limits on most "free" platforms is to nudge projects worth existing into a paid plan. The infrastructure to run them certainly isn't free.

Comment: violating a rule is not a precondition for downvoting a discussion.

Comment: This is true on the Q&A part of the site as well, by the way. There are *two* layers of quality control; a check against the rules, and what is useful; the latter is indicated through up and downvoting. Do not make the mistake of lumping the two layers together, they are isolated quality control processes which are for the most part not related to each other. And here is where it gets pretty icky - what is useful or not is subject to a personal opinion. Hence: one or two downvotes don't say anything yet. Me personally I pay more attention to a lack of upvotes, that says far more.

Comment: The link to the discussion is now dead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have at least three interesting discussions in there, none of which you invoked.

Discussions I imagine would be potentially interesting:

- What should I do upfront in my architecture so I can easily migrate my app and domain from the AWS free-tier to another tier / provider in case the AWS offering isn't in my budget range?
- How can I have my app accommodate large payloads that exceed my hosting plan without switching the whole stack to a different hosting provider?
- Given some hosting providers put your app to "sleep", what can I do to make sure my apps wakes up as quickly as possible, say under 5 seconds.

The above topics invite experts to share their knowledge and that is valuable in the future as well.

From the [discussion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines)

- Recommendations on software or tooling

  - Such posts should aim to start a discussion about the software or tool; they should not consist solely of a review/opinion.

I think your current discussion is just a "find me a hosting provider with a free plan that suits my not further detailed requirements" in disguise.

Knowing that the Linode free hosting plan is the best option in February 2024 can only be kept fresh till March 2024...